# Transaction count per month (since 2014 until 2016)

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2012, count

I have following table.
How can I be able to count per month (since 2014 until 2016) with earnings?

[image: transactions]

Comment: I forgot to include my code 
`SELECT    COUNT(*) as test
FROM      fschevrondata 
WHERE     YEAR(TxnDate) = '2014' 
GROUP BY  MONTH(TxnDate)`

Comment: there you go @fofik

Comment: What is the problem with that SQL? Do you need months, sum of earnings or something else? Please give more details.

Comment: Yes @fofik I need the total counts monthly for EarnValue

Comment: please add some sample table data and the expected result - as well in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question you need just add sum of earnings and year group.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as test, 
    SUM(EarnValue) as Total, 
    YEAR(TxnDate) as Year, 
    MONTH(TxnDate) as Month 
FROM fschevrondata 
WHERE 
    YEAR(TxnDate) >= 2014 -- or this can be TxnDate >= '2014-01-01'
    AND YEAR(TxnDate) <= 2016 -- or this can be TxnDate <= '2016-12-31'
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(TxnDate), 
    MONTH(TxnDate)
```